# Object Oriented Programming and calling a function

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I'm starting in development and for an exercise, I have to program in Object Oriented Programming. But I don't understand how to call my functions, and why my map disappears when I add the function `callback` and `onMarkerClick`

After many tutorials, I still don't get it. Thanks for the help.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stationscontract=xxxxxxxxxx&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {

  if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
    callback(xhr.responseText);

  } else {
    callback(xhr.status);
  }
});

xhr.addEventListener('error', function() {
  console.log("erreur de connexion");

});

xhr.send(null);


//This part of the code is on another js file
"use strict";

let carte = {
    lat: 43.6044,
    lng: 1.4442,
    zoom: 13,
    mapContainer: 'mapid',
    displayMap: '',
    addTo: '',
    idMap: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGhyb3VkIiwiYSI6ImNqczRndjIweDA0axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    layer: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}',
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',

    init: function() {
      this.mymap = L.map(this.mapContainer, {
        center: [this.lat, this.lng],
        zoom: this.zoom,
      })
    },

    display: function() {
      L.tileLayer(this.layer, {
        id: this.idMap,
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: this.attribution,
        accessToken: this.accessToken,
      }).addTo(this.mymap);
    },


    callback: function(response) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      response.forEach(function(info) {
        L.marker(
            [info.position.lat, info.position.lng], {
              "jcdecauxInfo": info
            }
          )
          .on('click', onMarkerClick)
          .addTo(this.mymap)
          .bindPopup(info.name);
      });
    }

    onMarkerClick: function(arg) {

      let marker = arg.target;

      let info = marker.options.jcdecauxInfo;
      let address = info.address;
      let bikeStands = info.bike_stands;
      let availableBikes = info.available_bikes;
      let statusStation = info.status;

      document.getElementById("info-station").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("adresse-station").innerText = address;
      document.getElementById("place-libre").innerText = bikeStands;
      document.getElementById("velo-dispo").innerText = availableBikes;
      document.getElementById("etat-station").innerText = statusStation;
    };
```

Comment: You should check the error console before posting questions. It looks like you are missing a comma between the `onMarkerClick` and `onMarkerClick` methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you save the functions as props on `carte` you can just call functions like so:

`carte.init()`

BTW, You have these mistakes in your code:

- You don't have a `,` after the function called `callback`:
- You are not closing the `carte` object.

```js
let carte = {

    callback : function(response) {
      // ...
    }
    // ↑ you need a , here!!!

    onMarkerClick : function(arg) {
      // ...
    }
    // no ; here!!!

};
// ↑ you need to close `carte` here
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I made the changes and calls my functions :                      
carte.init();
carte.display();
carte.callback();
carte.onMarkerClick();
And now i have this error : 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.callback (script.js:44)
    at script.js:79

There is a problem with my function callback she's not defined or something ?

Comment: Add `console.log(response)` in front of JSON.parse. You’re probably not getting any result or the result is not an array. If you’re gonna call carte.callback() you need to pass the response there!!

Comment: when i put console.log(response) in front of JSON.parse, yes get undefined. But 
i'm forced to call my callback function right ? So i don't get how to response.

Comment: If you want to call your function called callback from xhr.addEvenListener, you’ll also have to write `carte.callback(xhr.responseText)` in there.

Comment: However, i think the discussion is not appropriate for a QA format any more. If you have any further question you better post a new question. If you just want to discuss various things on how JavaScript works, you better use Reddit or a forum instead of StackOverflow.